# Map primary key from an nested object field

Tags: android, realm

I have a RealmObject class with a Object and it's actual PrimaryKey as a String in this objects. But it is not allowed to have an Object as an Primary key.

```
public class Model extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private Id _id;
    ...
}

public class Id extends RealmObject {
    private String id; // the primary key for the class Model
    ...
}
```

Because it is not possible to change the response structure of the server currently I tried different approaches to work around the problem. But non of them worked so far. I'm using "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.87.2" as and "realm-android" plugin for my project in Android Studio.

1.

```
public class Model extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private Id _id;

    public String getId() {
        return _id.getId();
    }
    ...
}
```

2.

```
public class Model extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("_id.id")
    private String id;
    private Id _id;
    ...
}
```

How would you solve it? Is it possible with Realm only or do I have to use a second tool like the gson library?

EDIT:

Thank you beeender for the answer! It is working but if someone has a better solution you are welcome.

```
            JSONArray jsonArray = null;
            try {
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(total.toString());
                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = jsonObject.getJSONObject("_id").getString("id");
                    jsonObject.put("id", id);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: I think in this special case you need to parse the JSON by yourself. Store the `Id.idString` as the `Model.idString` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you beeender for the answer! It is working but if someone has a better solution you are welcome.

```
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        try {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(total.toString());
            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = jsonObject.getJSONObject("_id").getString("id");
                jsonObject.put("id", id);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```